# Изменение загруженного файла django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь разобраться в джанго. У меня появилась такая задача: пользователь загружает xml файл, а я должен его обработать и вернуть определенные данные. У меня уже есть десктопный скрипт для этого с использованием xlrd и openpyexel. Вопрос вот в чем: как сразу обрабатывать полученный файл и сразу выводить данные пользователю?

мой forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import files

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = files
        fields = ('File',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class files(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='files', null=True,)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import DocumentForm

def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('portfolio:index')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'templates/upload/upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

upload.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'portfolio:index' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Вам не нужна модель, если вы не собираетесь хранить файл в базе. В документации это просто и доходчиво [описано с примерами](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем views.py после строки:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

Берете свой файл (`request.FILES`) обрабатывайте его, и показывайте страничку с результатами. Как отметил предыдущий оратор, сохранять для этого не обязательно и модель Вам не нужна.